# Iterating over Variadic arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find something as simple as what I'm trying to do. Essentially, I just want to make sure the code *triggers* each parameter, calling any functions that may be sent as inputs. My biggest worry here is that optimizations may remove some of the calls, changing the result.

I **was** using the following syntax. It seemed to trigger the function calls the way I want, but it has the strange result of triggering the arguments in reverse order - the last argument is called first, and the first argument is called last:

```
template <typename... PARMS> uint PARMS_COUNT(PARMS&& ... parms) { return static_cast<uint>( sizeof...(parms) ); }
```

This was my first guess as to how to do the same thing (*edit: this does not change the order - it still happens in reverse, because the order is being determined by the function parameter evaluation, rather than what order the function uses them in*):

```
template <typename FIRST>
constexpr uint PARMS_EXPAND(FIRST &&first)
{
    return static_cast<uint>( sizeof(first) > 0 ? 1 : 0 );
}
template <typename FIRST,typename... PARMS>
constexpr uint PARMS_EXPAND(FIRST &&first,PARMS&& ... parms)
{
    return static_cast<uint>( sizeof(first) > 0 ? 1 : 0 ) + PARMS_EXPAND( std::forward<PARMS>(parms)... );
}
```

I tested this in a few places, but then realized that regardless of how much testing I do, I'll never know if this is a safe way to do it. Is there a standard or well known method to pull this logic off? Or even better, some built in system to iterate over the arguments and "access them" in the correct order?

To better explain why I would want to trigger code like this, consider a function that can add new objects to a parent:

```
void AddObject(/*SINGLE UNKNOWN INPUT*/)
{
    ...
}
template <typename... PARMS> AddObjects(PARMS&& ... parms)
{
    PARAMS_EXPAND( AddObject(parms)... );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Arguments are not guaranteed to be evaluated in any specific order, the only guarantee is that the evaluation of them does not overlap.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to call `()` on each parameter passed to the function, in order from the first parameter to the last one?

Comment: try compiling without any optimization.

Comment: Why do you need a function for this? Just call the functions you need to call. *"optimizations may remove some of the calls, changing the result"* The only allowed optimizations are those that don't change the program behavior.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Does your `AddObjects()` actually care about the order the arguments are evaluated? (as opposed to the order `AddObject()` is called on each argument) If you're simply going to pass variables (rather than e.g. function calls), the order doesn't matter, and you can do `(AddObjects(parms), ...);` to call `AddObjects` on each parameter.

Comment: Only one input argument per object created, but the order they are added should match the parameter inputs. Or at least that's what I was after.

Comment: As long as you can use C++17, `PARAMS_EXPAND( AddObject(parms)... );` can just be `(AddObject(parms), ...);`

Comment: How exactly are you "sending functions as inputs"? Do you mean the results of function calls (like your `AddObject`, although that returns `void`) are the arguments? Or are function call parameters somehow evaluated in the callee, like passing lambdas?

Comment: I guess I didn't choose the best wording there. I just meant that any function calls being sent as arguments needed to be executed as the arguments are iterated over, rather than sizeof(x) returning the size of the function's return value, which I was worried might happen.

Comment: I did not know about the syntax `(AddObject(parms), ...)` . What is happening there exactly? Some type of Lambda? Btw, my version of the argument iteration also calls the arguments in the reverse order. I guess there's no way to control which argument gets triggered first?

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying to comments, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, it looks like your magic syntax does call them in the correct order. Is that just a happy accident, or will that always work?

Comment: This is called a *fold expression*. Do you understand that two different orders are involved here? The order `AddObject`s are called (this is easy to get right), and the order the arguments are evaluated (if you do `AddObjects(foo(), bar())`, whether `foo()` or `bar()` will be called first). This order is unspecified and is controlled by the caller, and you can't do anything with it in your function.

Comment: @Robert That'll always work as it is a fold expression using the comma operator, which is always evaluated in order from left to right.

Comment: Fold expressions are new to me. Thanks for pointing them out. Yeah, I was aware of the two separate orderings (parameter evaluation vs function body "activation"). But I sometimes wonder how much the code might change once the compiler gets ahold of it. But I also wasn't aware of the fact that function parameters are evaluated from right to left. Learning a bunch today, apparently.

Comment: @Robert *But I also wasn't aware of the fact that function parameters are evaluated from right to left* There is no guaranteed order of evaluation for function parameters. Some compilers process left to right, others right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
void AddObject(T);

template <typename... PARMS> AddObjects(PARMS&& ... parms)
{
    PARAMS_EXPAND( AddObject(parms)... );
}
```

you're making a single top-level function call to `PARAMS_EXPAND` with `sizeof...(PARMS)` arguments.

What happens inside `PARAMS_EXPAND` is essentially irrelevant because, like every other function call, the arguments are evaluated *before* the function is entered. And, like every other function call, the argument expressions are [intederminately sequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator) with respect to each other.

So, your goal of evaluating `AddObject(parms)` for each parameter in order has failed before control reaches inside `PARAMS_EXPAND` at all.

Fortunately, C++17 gave us a way of evaluating operations on parameter packs in order without relying on function call semantics: the [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
(AddObject(parms), ...);
```

Although this *looks* a bit like a function call, it's actually a right fold over the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), expanded like

```
(AddObject(p0) , (... , (AddObject(pN-1) , AddObject(PN))));
```

which does indeed evaluate its arguments in left-to-right order, exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I answer the original question because it's not clear what you're asking for (see comment) later. If you want n arguments to be called in order, i.e. call `operator()` on them (e.g. for lambdas, functors), you can do:

```
constexpr void callEach() {}

template<typename F, typename... Fs>
constexpr void callEach(F f, Fs&&... fs)
{
    f();
    callEach(std::forward<Fs>(fs)...);
}
```

Any way that doesn't take lambdas cannot guarantee evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
PARAMS_EXPAND( AddObject(parms)... );
```

the order of evaluation is not specified because there is no sequence point between each item. Also I'm confused as to why `PARAMS_EXPAND` does anything if you are going to discard the result. It might as well be this:

```
template <typename... PARMS>
void PARAMS_EXPAND(PARMS&&...) {}
```

If you just want to call `AddObject` with each `parms` in order, then you need to pass the function and the parameters separately:

```
void print(int i) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}

template <typename F, typename Head>
constexpr void call_for_each(F&& f, Head&& head)
{
    f(head);
}
template <typename F, typename Head, typename... Tail>
constexpr void call_for_each(F&& f, Head&& head, Tail&&... tail)
{
    f(std::forward<Head>(head));
    call_for_each(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void print_all(Args&&... args)
{
    call_for_each(print, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/czPfba8oj)

Here the calls are correctly sequenced: first call `f` with `head`, then make the recursive call for the rest of the arguments in `tail`.

In C++17, you can use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
constexpr void call_for_each(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    (f(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dGjPWboqn)

This basically generates a line like so:

```
(f(std::forward<Args0>(args0), f(std::forward<Args1>(args1), ..., f(std::forward<ArgsN>(argsN));
```

where `ArgsI` and `argsI` are the I-th element of `Args` and `args` in the correct order.

Here, the calls are again correctly sequenced because of [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).